# Align image to left of text on same line - Twitter Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

Currently I have a paragraph heading and an image to its right, on the same line:

```
<div class="paragraphs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="content-heading"><h3>Experience &nbsp </h3><img src="../site/img/success32.png"/></div>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine - the content-heading and the image are on the same line. However, when I put the image before the content-heading div, they are no longer on the same line. This is what I want to achieve - image then content-heading - on the same line.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use floating:

```
<div class="paragraphs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <img style="float:left" src="../site/img/success32.png"/>
      <div class="content-heading"><h3>Experience &nbsp </h3></div>
      <p style="clear:both">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the following `<p>` to stay at the same line too, remove its

```
style="clear:both"
```

but then you should add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

after it.

Answer (score 87):

Using Twitter Bootstrap classes may be the best choice :

- `pull-left` makes an element floating left
- `clearfix` allows the element to contain floating elements (if not already set via another class)

```html
<div class="paragraphs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="clearfix content-heading">
          <img class="pull-left" src="../site/img/success32.png"/>
          <h3>Experience &nbsp </h3>
      </div>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, there are special classes in [Bootstrap for media](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#media) (e.g. images) aligned the poster wanted it: _media_, _media\_header_ and _media\_body_

Comment: @RaulPinto Indeed, but it's not really permissive, and it doesn't match the layout of the OP : http://jsbin.com/ipuyut/2/edit

Comment: How do I keep the text centered with the image?

Comment: @Imray There is not one solution for vertical alignment. Search around and pick your best match (keywords vertical alignment text image)

Answer (score 48):

Starting with Bootstrap v3.3.0 you can use `.media-left` and `.media-body`

```
<div class="media">
    <span class="media-left">
        <img src="../site/img/success32.png" alt="...">
    </span>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h3 class="media-heading">Experience</h3>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media

Answer (score 8):

For Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="paragraphs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content-heading clearfix media">
           <h3>Experience &nbsp </h3>
           <img class="pull-left" src="../site/img/success32.png"/>
      </div>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: span4 isn't used in Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 6):

I would use Bootstrap's grid to achieve the desired result.  The class="img-responsive" works nicely. Something like:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><img src="./pictures/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Some picture" width="410" height="307"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><h1>Heading</h1><p>Your Information.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would like to know why as well.  I've used this approach before, and it has worked for me.  Based on the question asked, it seemed like an appropriate solution.

Comment: It adds a bunch of padding both to the image and to the text.

Comment: @StefanD There are many different ways to fix the padding/gutter.  Here are a couple of answers that may help: [How to adjust gutter in Bootstrap 3 grid system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911763/how-to-adjust-gutter-in-bootstrap-3-grid-system) or [Bootstrap 3 Gutter Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041733/bootstrap-3-gutter-size/19044326)

Answer (score 3):

Use Nesting column

To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of .col-sm-* columns within an existing .col-sm-* column. Nested rows should include a set of columns that add up to 12 or fewer (it is not required that you use all 12 available columns).

[image]

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    Level 1: .col-sm-9
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```