# Reduce the gutter (default 30px) on smaller devices in Bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3 the gutter is defined as 30px (15px on each side of a column). The issue I'm running is that, for example if I shrink my screen down to be tiny, the gutters end up being wider than the columns themselves, as seen below (darker blue = column, lighter blue = gutter).

[image]

Can you modify the gutter width of certain resolution states? (mobile, tablet, etc)

Answer (score 26):

The gutter is construct by a left and right padding, you could use media queries to change this depending on your screen size:

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) 
{ 
    div[class^="col"]{padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;}
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) 
{   
    div[class^="col"]{padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;}
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) 
{   
    /*default so you don't need this*/
    div[class^="col"]{padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;}
}
```

Note see also this question: [Bootstrap 3 Gutter Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041733/bootstrap-3-gutter-size/19044326). You should use this when you also want to change the 'visual' gutter on both side of the grid. In this case you will also have to set the padding of the .container class to your gutter size. b.e.

```
/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) 
{   
    /*default so you don't need this*/
    div[class^="col"]{padding-left:85px; padding-right:85px;}
    .container{padding-left:85px; padding-right:85px;}
    .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we use % on those padding changes, or will bootstrap 3 complain?

Comment: If, like me, you don't use the attribute matching selectors too often and don't want to look them up, read on! I had pretty good success changing `[class^="col"]` (starts with "col") to `[class*="col"]` (attribute contains "col"). If you have more than one class on your element and `col-` isn't the first, the `*=` is what you'll need.

Answer (score 6):

A more robust solution, using bootstrap mixins:

```
@sm-gutter: 10px;
@md-gutter: 50px;
@lg-gutter: 100px;

.my-container {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: @container-sm;
    .container-fixed(@gutter: @sm-gutter);
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: @container-md;
    .container-fixed(@gutter: @md-gutter);
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
    .container-fixed(@gutter: @lg-gutter);
  }
}

.my-row {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .make-row(@gutter: @sm-gutter);
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    .make-row(@gutter: @md-gutter);
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    .make-row(@gutter: @lg-gutter);
  }
}

.my-4-col {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .make-sm-column(4, @sm-gutter);
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
     .make-md-column(4, @md-gutter);
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
     .make-lg-column(4, @lg-gutter);
  }
}
```

Comment: These are less mixins i guess?

Comment: @ratata: Yes, they're for Less.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution using the LESS mixin and "col" class:

```
.reduce-gutter(@size: 5px) {
    .row {
        .make-row(@size);
    }
    .row .col:first-child,
    .row .col:last-child { 
        padding-right: @size;
        padding-left: @size;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me.  I don't know why someone downvoted it.

Comment: `:last-child` is not supported by IE8 and this might be a problem. IE8 is generally supported by bootstrap but this solution would break the column flow.

Comment: If you have more than two columns in your layout this wil break. Lose the first-child & last-child.

Answer (score 1):

I use standard (30px) gutter size except on small devices where my gutter is 6px :

```
@media (max-width: $screen-sm-min - 1) {
    $grid-gutter-width: 6px; // redefining

    // also redefine $navbar-padding-horizontal in the scope because it depend on $grid-gutter-width
    $navbar-padding-horizontal: floor(($grid-gutter-width / 2));

    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap/forms";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap/grid";
    @import "../bootstrap/bootstrap/navbar";
}
```

Comment: This would be a nice approach, but I could not bring this to work. Can you provide me more information where to place your code, and why do I need to re-import some bootstrap files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rewrite Bootstrap mixin in order to have half of the normal grid-gutter for the XS width. Seems work fine.

```
.make-xs-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {   
    @media(max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
        padding-left:  (@gutter / 4);
        padding-right: (@gutter / 4);
    };
}
.make-row(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
    @media(max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
        margin-left:  (@gutter / -4);
        margin-right: (@gutter / -4);
    }
}

.container-fixed() {
    @media(max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
        padding-left:  (@grid-gutter-width / 4);
        padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 4);
    }
}
```