# How to customize bootstrap3 @grid-gutter-width for only .col-xs-

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'd like to have thinner gutters when rendered on mobile devices. I found this in `mixins.less` to let me set `@grid-gutter-width` globally. But what's the best way to set a different gutter width for ONLY `col-xs-` (mobile devices) when the columns are all collapsed without breaking everything else?

```
// Grid System
// -----------

// Centered container element
.container-fixed() {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left:  (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  .clearfix();
}

// Creates a wrapper for a series of columns
.make-row(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  margin-left:  (@gutter / -2);
  margin-right: (@gutter / -2);
  .clearfix();
}

// Generate the extra small columns
.make-xs-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
  min-height: 1px;
  // Inner gutter via padding
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to edit the XS mixins yourself to use a new, separate variable (instead of `@grid-gutter-width`). We're probably going to add per-grid-tier gutter width variables in Bootstrap v4.

Comment: thanks - at least I know what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good answer here that will solve this problem: [Reduce the gutter (default 30px) on smaller devices in Bootstrap3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164377/reduce-the-gutter-default-30px-on-smaller-devices-in-bootstrap3)
i.e.:

```
/* Extra-small devices (767px and below) */
@media (max-width: 767px) 
{ 
    div[class^="col-xs-"] {
        padding-left: 5px; 
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

Of course, you might to wrap that up in LESS.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to change gutter size you must open the `variable.less`, and look for

`@grid-gutter-width:`
and change it to your desired value.

**Tips:**
you can also change/edit number of columns, container width inside the `variable.less`.

Comment: that would change the grid gutter width globally, my question was for changing gutter width for ONLY col-xs-