# Bootstrap 3 - reducing gutter size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gutter

What I want to achieve is:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CPb8vAu.png]

While so far it looks like this (bottom margins aren't the issue, I decided that they should be smaller):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2SKqx0P.png]

Unfortunately the gutter size is based on padding that is marked as the grey part in the image up. I would like each part to have the same size: 15 px.

The part of code I am referring to is (where groups-margin sets bottom margin for each button):

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 groups-margin">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 1 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 3</span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 2 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 1</span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 3 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 3</span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 4 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 6</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 groups-margin">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 5 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 4</span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 6 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 6</span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 7 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 7</span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 8 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 2</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Please include the code you used to generate the output.

Comment: Auch, of course, I have completely forgotten about the most important part...

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164377/reduce-the-gutter-default-30px-on-smaller-devices-in-bootstrap3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `col-sm-6` with a div, say `.input-row` like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 groups-margin">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 1 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 3</span></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 2 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 1</span></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 3 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 3</span></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 4 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 6</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 groups-margin">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 5 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 4</span></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 6 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 6</span></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 7 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 7</span></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block outline" href="#">Grupa 8 <span class="group-stations-count">Stacje: 2</span></a>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now since you're using `col-sm-`, add these properties within a media query like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .input-row .col-sm-6:first-child{padding-right:7.5px;}
    .input-row .col-sm-6:last-child{padding-left:7.5px;}
}
```

Now all gutters (left, right and middle will be 15px)

---

Here's a jsfiddle with the above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/47/

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This solved my problem : )

Comment: Glad I could help Jakub :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want increased gutter size to only that section, you can make a class for it.

```
.btn .gutter{
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

and you can just add gutter in with the classes

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md gutter">some button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to create more specific row classes, leaving Bootstrap’s intact. So I may have something like this:

```less
.row-half-gutter {
  margin-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2) * -1;
  margin-left: (@grid-gutter-width / 2) * -1;

  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 4);
    padding-left: (@grid-gutter-width / 4);
  }
}

.row-no-gutter {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```