# How to remove the spacing between the columns or grids in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a tile view using bootstrap grids but i dont want the spacing between any adjacent columns or rows. i tried many ways to remove but I am not able to. Can any one please help with the same ?

Following is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-xs-12">

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    //a vertical long image
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        //square image
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        //square image
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <!-- <horizontal image> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xs-12 pull-right">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" >
                 //square image
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" >
             //vertical long image
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing closing on this div `<div class="row"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce the gutter (default 30px) on smaller devices in Bootstrap3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164377/reduce-the-gutter-default-30px-on-smaller-devices-in-bootstrap3)

Comment: Still not able to work out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove padding from columns in Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap does not provide such functionality, but it is easy to have the grid columns without having the extra space.

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

You can easily use the `.no-gutter` class by adding it to the `.row` class.

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Source: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-still-might-not-know

Comment: still there is a space between two columns. This isn't working

Comment: Can it be due to the img tag ?

Comment: In that case, I believe I didn't really understand what you are looking for. Can you provide a demo (e.g. jsfiddle or bootply) that shows exactly the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`col-*-*` by default have `padding-left/right: 15px` so you to reset to `0`

```css
.container [class^="col"] {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-xs-12">

      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
          //a vertical long image
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            //square image
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            //square image
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <!-- <horizontal image> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xs-12 pull-right">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        //square image
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        //vertical long image
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but this would remove the spacing from all the columns, wherever col is used ! right ?

Comment: you said you didn't any space from any col.. but you can specify which column you want to reset the `padding`

Comment: With that I mean, apart from this code I have used the col attribute at many other places in my website. So, using this will remove the space from this code as well from others. but i want to remove the spacing specifically for this.

Comment: Use an id to .container then apply only to the ID