# Bootstrap Gutters

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and exploring the documentation I have been encountering the Gutters term quite and am not able to properly understand what the terminology refers. It would be great if a clear answer can be provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the following:

> negative `margins` on `.row` and the horizontal `padding` on all immediate children columns

You can use the `.no-gutters` class to remove this default styling.

```css
.col-sm {
  background: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.35);
}

.no-gutters .col-sm {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,255,.35);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        COLUMN
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        COLUMN
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        COLUMN
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container no-gutters">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-sm">
        COLUMN
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        COLUMN
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        COLUMN
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe just a fancy term for the default padding that bootstrap (3 and 4) adds around columns (15px padding on both sides of column).

Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041733/bootstrap-3-gutter-size?answertab=active#tab-top) might be helpful in understanding it better.