# How to adjust gutter in Bootstrap 3 grid system?

Tags: margin, padding, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system, gutter

The new Bootstrap 3 grid system is great. It's more powerful for responsive design at all screen sizes, and much easier for nested.

But I have one issue I could not figure out. How do I add precise gap between the columns? Say I have container 960px, 3 columns at 310px and 2 gutters at 15px in between 3 columns. How do I do that?

Comment: This seems nice. The first result i like. Most just don't display the padding which makes the text go stand against the edge.
I try to reproduce your answer using jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/0ddum192/ But I don't have a gutter. Does someone know what goes wrong?

Answer (score 17):

You could create a CSS class for this and apply it to your columns. Since the gutter (spacing between columns) is controlled by padding in Bootstrap 3, adjust the padding accordingly:

```
.col {
  padding-right:7px;
  padding-left:7px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/93473

***EDIT*** If you only want the spacing between columns you can select all cols except first and last like this..

```
.col:not(:first-child,:last-child) {
  padding-right:7px;
  padding-left:7px;
}
```

## [Updated Bootply](http://bootply.com/93473)

For Bootstrap 4 see: [Remove gutter space for a specific div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489307/remove-gutter-space-for-a-specific-div-only)

Comment: But this way it will add padding to the first child as well. This is not exactly what I want. 
What I am thinking is, maybe I can add make the container 975px, and add padding-right: 15px; to .col. When screen size change, I have to remove that padding-right: 15px;. Also, if I have other elements on the page. I need to add this padding-right: 15px; and remove it when screen size change.
I am not sure if this is the best way to handle the columns with gutter in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I don't think that you need to mention first child or the last child as all the column elements in bootstrap 3 adhere to the same margin or padding on the left and the right side.

Answer (score 6):

To define a 3 column grid you could use the [customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) or download the source set your less variables and recompile.

To learn more about the grid and the columns / gutter widths, please also read:

- [Bootstrap 3 - Set Container Width to 940px Maximum for Desktops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430217/bootstrap-3-set-container-width-to-940px-maximum-for-desktops/19434913)
- [Why does Bootstrap 3 force the container width to certain sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393264/why-does-bootstrap-3-force-the-container-width-to-certain-sizes/19411815#19411815)
- [Bootstrap 3 Gutter Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041733/bootstrap-3-gutter-size/19044326)
- [Reduce the gutter (default 30px) on smaller devices in Bootstrap3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164377/reduce-the-gutter-default-30px-on-smaller-devices-in-bootstrap3/19179407)

In you case with a container of 960px consider the medium grid (see also: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). This grid will have a max container width of 970px.
When setting `@grid-columns:3;` and setting `@grid-gutter-width:15px;` in variables.less you will get:

```
15px | 1st column (298.33) | 15px | 2nd column (298.33) |15px | 3th column (298.33) | 15px
```

Comment: +1 Downloading the LESS file, in regards to Bootstrap 3.3.6, is perhaps the most efficient way to do this.  Who really wants to go into a .CSS file and manually modify x number of Bootstraps selectors??? and only to do it again when another Bootstrap project is needed? Allow LESS to do all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 3):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I believe I figured it out.

In my case, I added `[class*="col-"] {padding: 0 7.5px;};`.

Then added `.row {margin: 0 -7.5px;}`.

This works pretty well, except there is 1px margin on both sides. So I just make `.row {margin: 0 -7.5px;}` to `.row {margin: 0 -8.5px;}`, then it works perfectly.

I have no idea why there is a 1px margin. Maybe someone can explain it?

See the sample I created:

[Demo](http://bootply.com/render/93548)
[Code](http://bootply.com/93548)

Comment: When you're nesting rows or you have rows with one or two columns, you need to be a bit more specific:

`div[class^="col-"]:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left:7px;
}
div[class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:7px;
}`