# Bootstrap grid margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nH5WP/

It's a super simple 3 x 3 grid using Bootstrap 3

I want to add margins to the right and bottom of each block.

The last block in each line is dropping down, I would normally remove the right margin on the last block in each line with something like

```
.box:last-child{
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

How can I add margins between each block in this grid ?

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>One</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Two</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Three</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Four</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Five</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Six</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Seven</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Eight</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 box">
            <p>Nine</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't create a "gutter" in the bootstrap grid system using `margin:`.

Bootstrap uses padding to build gutters, so you need to put a wrapper div around your columns and pads that.

See [How to adjust gutter in Bootstrap 3 grid system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911763/bootstrap-3-grid-system-with-gutter) for more information.

Comment: Updated how the above Jsfiddle would work if the Bootstrap padding based grid is applied: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzw3yyg0/

Answer (score 3):

Apply `width:calc(33.33% - 10px);` in box class.

Answer (score -6):

Change each:

```
class="col-xs-4 box"
```

to

```
class="col-xs-3 box"
```

You can see it in http://jsfiddle.net/nH5WP/8/

Comment: But then it's not full width, I need to with margins but full window