# How to show two columns in Bootstrap Grid System closer than what the default is

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

In the following HTML I'm using Bootstrap. The real display as shown in image below has two columns too far apart. How can I make them display a bit closer to each other.

**NOTE**: For the sake of brevity of this post, I've simplified the html a bit. The real html involves some programming code - such as foreach loop and data fetch from database etc - as that all is not related to this post.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td class="col-md-2">
                    <a href="some link">item1</a>
                 </td>
                 <td class="col-md-10">
                   <span>item2</span>
                 </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Display**:

[image]

**UPDATE**: If I change first column `<td class="col-md-2">` to `<td class="col-md-1">` and the second column `<td class="col-md-10">` to `<td class="col-md-11">` the content in first column gets wrapped (something I don't want since all the content in first column is of fixed length and hence it does not need to be wrapped).

Comment: I've tried your updated code and it does not wrap for me. The first column expands. Is the width of your div constrained?

Comment: The gutter (spacing between columns in always 30px) so you'd need to customize it or not use the grid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911763/how-to-adjust-gutter-in-bootstrap-3-grid-system

Answer (score 1):

To address your updated code with the first column changed to col-md-1, you can add text-nowrap to solve your wrapping issue:

```
<td class="col-md-1; text-nowrap">
```

Comment: Your solution works. Is it the correct approach or there are better alternatives?

Comment: Well, this is just one of many possible solutions. text-nowrap is a valid bootstrap element. I don't think it would impact performance or cause any negative rendering issues.