# align two images and text on the same line boostrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i basically have an text in between and two images around it one on right and the other on left
but when ever i try to align it either one of the images gets to the next line whereas i want them on the same line here the code

```
   <div style="background-color:#ddb56c;clear: both; " class="container">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" >
        <div class="clearfix">
            <img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="images/Homepage_03.png" style="max-width: 100%;"/>
            <h1>Maroon Decor</h1>
            <img class="img-responsive pull-right" src="images/Homepage_05.png" style="max-width: 100%;" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900457/align-image-to-left-of-text-on-same-line-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: i was reading this post actually my is different because i have two images the left image and text are perfectly aligned but the issue arises in the right image that goes to the second line

Comment: What do you want actually? Image+h1+Image? Like this in screen?

Comment: exactly! what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this actually. You have to divide your screen in `3 + 6 + 3`. Put one image in `div 3` then text in `div 6` and then another image in `div 3`

**If you use all `col-lg-x col-xs-x col-sm-x col-md-3` then it will be same design for all device.

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="images/Homepage_03.png" style="max-width: 100%;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" >
        <div class="clearfix">

            <h1>Maroon Decor</h1>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <img class="img-responsive pull-right" src="images/Homepage_05.png" style="max-width: 100%;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it did the job but the mobile view gets messed up

Comment: that did the trick! thanks man unfortunately can't Up vote Your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can display the header inline.

```
<style>
h1 {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

Comment: well that was exactly what i want just one more thing the things are aligned but the text is at the top looking pretty i tried to gave some padding but it wont come down possible way to get it centered vertically?